# How to make sense of the Etherscan logs API?

Tags: etherscan, python, logs, explorer-api

I'm trying to practice making api calls to etherscan using python, and I built a function that calls the Get Event Logs endpoint for the staked aave address: 0x4da27a545c0c5B758a6BA100e3a049001de870f5.

The code works, but I don't know how to convert the results into a readable format. For example, how could I translate
'timeStamp': '0x5f763d30'
into a human readable date time format?

Is it possible?

Here is one entry that is returned:

{'status': '1', 'message': 'OK', 'result': [{'address': '0x4da27a545c0c5b758a6ba100e3a049001de870f5', 'topics': ['0x7e644d79422f17c01e4894b5f4f588d331ebfa28653d42ae832dc59e38c9798f'], 'data': '0x0000000000000000000000008a2efd9a790199f4c94c6effe210fce0b4724f52000000000000000000000000a133459b2502b0137e85a446fa8d4e300877a007', 'blockNumber': '0xa76cd2', 'blockHash': '0xa599c98566148fcc93ab4bd3107c09ebf9c5235d10161ad3ddcee8c901b6ddc1', 'timeStamp': '0x5f763d30', 'gasPrice': '0x113abe6400', 'gasUsed': '0x29fe2', 'logIndex': '0x5c', 'transactionHash': '0x9a6b0b9d3c63e82fa21d6d6d0627e7d6cc25b088278e87c3e3f4f012dcbf4e38', 'transactionIndex': '0x1f'}

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in python but these are hex values and could be converted to decimal using int('0x5f763d30', 16) which gives unix timestamp 1601584432 or Thursday, 1 October 2020 20:33:52 GMT